# API Nested JSON Response TO CSV

Tags: python, json, csv, pandas

I am trying to convert a Nested JSON Response to CSV. Following is the JSON Response

```
{
"rows": [
[
{
"postId": 188365573,
"messageId": 198365562,
"accountId": 214,
"messageType": 2,
"channelType": "TWITTER",
"accountType": "TWITTER",
"taxonomy": {
  "campaignId": "2521_4",
  "clientCustomProperties": {
    "PromotionChannelAbbreviation": [
      "3tw"
    ],
    "PromotionChannels": [
      "Twitter"
    ],
    "ContentOwner": [
      "Audit"
    ],
    "Location": [
      "us"
    ],
    "Sub_Category": [
      "dbriefs"
    ],
    "ContentOwnerAbbreviation": [
      "aud"
    ],
    "PrimaryPurpose_Outcome": [
      "Engagement"
    ],
    "PrimaryPurposeOutcomeAbbv": [
      "eng"
    ]
  },
  "partnerCustomProperties": {},
  "tags": [],
  "urlShortnerDomain": "2721_spr.ly"
},
"approval": {
  "approvalOption": "NONE",
  "comment": ""
},
"status": "SENT",
"createdDate": 1433331585000,
"scheduleDate": 1435783440000,
"version": 4,
"deleted": false,
"publishedDate": 1435783441000,
"statusID": "6163465412728176",
"permalink": "https://twitter.com/Acctg/status/916346541272498176",
"additional": {
  "links": []
  }
 },
 0
 ],
[
{
"postId": 999145171,
"messageId": 109145169,
"accountId": 21388,
"messageType": 2,
"channelType": "TWITTER",
"accountType": "TWITTER",
"taxonomy": {
  "campaignId": "2521_4",
  "clientCustomProperties": {
    "PromotionChannelAbbreviation": [
      "3tw"
    ],
    "Eminence_Registry_Number": [
      "1000159"
    ],
    "PromotionChannels": [
      "Twitter"
    ],
    "ContentOwner": [
      "Ctr. Health Solutions"
    ],
    "Location": [
      "us"
    ],
    "Sub_Category": [
      "fraud"
    ],
    "ContentOwnerAbbreviation": [
      "chs"
    ],
    "PrimaryPurpose_Outcome": [
      "Awareness"
    ],
    "PrimaryPurposeOutcomeAbbv": [
      "awa"
    ]
  },
  "partnerCustomProperties": {},
  "tags": [],
  "urlShortnerDomain": "2521_spr.ly"
},
"approval": {
  "approvalOption": "NONE",
  "comment": ""
},
"status": "SENT",
"createdDate": 1434983660000,
"scheduleDate": 1435753800000,
"version": 4,
"deleted": false,
"publishedDate": 1435753801000,
"statusID": "616222222198407168",
"permalink": "https://twitter.com/Health/status/6162222221984070968",
"additional": {
  "links": []
}
},
 0
]   
}
```

And the python code I am using to covert this is

```
import json
import csv 

# importing the data 
with open('Post_Insights_test.json') as Test:
data1 = json.load(Test)

# opening the csv 
csvdata= open('Data_table2.csv', 'w')
csvwriter = csv.writer(csvdata, delimiter=',')

#Taking the keys out from 1st dict, that too which aren't nested
header= data1["rows"][1][0].keys()
csvwriter.writerow(header)

for i in range(0,70):
  csvwriter.writerow(data1["rows"][i][0].values())

csvdata.close()
```

Problems are following:

1. Unable to get the keys for nested responses like taxonomy
2. Unable to get the values for nested responses like taxonomy
3. Many responses have different headers/ keys, so ideally I should have them as headers in my excel, but I am not able to figure out how to do it in python
4. My excel sheet shows gap of row after every entry , I dont know why

Please help. All criticism are welcome. Kind Regards

Comment: Can you post an example of what you'd want your CSV to look like (with headers and data rows? Like do you want every subkey of `taxonomy` to be its own column? Will there be a finite number of headers total once you process all your responses, or could responses just have arbitrarily different headers? Do you already know all the types of responses you could get?

Comment: FYI, your JSON here is invalid. A closing bracket is missing to end the "rows" array.

Comment: Hi Biryee- Thanks for your response. Yes I want all the subkeys of taxonomy as headers, there will be finite numbers of headers but as you have mentioned there could be different headers in different response, so in that case a new column should be created for that key/ subkey. I dont know, how to paste the csv/ excel format here? Can you Pls help